# Why does calling the variable in this if statement give me a syntax error. What rule am I missing here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, syntax-error

I am using python 3. I'm trying to understand why this code gives me a syntax error on my third line where it says "If not n % 2 == 0". I think there is some rule I am missing. What I'm trying to is impose some conditions on an inputted integer to give me a specific output.

```
n = int(input().strip()) 

def find_weird(n):
If not n % 2 == 0:
return "Weird"

Elif n % 2 == 0 and N < 5 and N > 2:
return "Not Weird"

Elif n % 2 == 0 and N < 20 and N > 6:
return "Weird"

Elif n % 2 == 0 and N > 20:
return "Not Weird"
```

Edit: Sorry, not properly copying the code snippet was my fault here (in the actual IDE I indented properly). It was the capitalization that got me at the end of the day. Sigh, what a way to post a first question on here. So embarrassing!

Comment: Python is space- and case-sensitive. You need to make all the `If` and `Elif` lowercase and properly indent your code.

Comment: Also, `not ... == 0` is the same as `... != 0`

Comment: @jonrsharpe. Where do you see `print`?

Comment: btw, mind the indentation for the blocks (4 spaces; spaces, not tab). Your code is all left aligned.

Comment: Sorry, not properly copying the code snippet was my fault here (in the actual IDE I indented properly). It was the capitalization that got me at the end of the day. Sigh, what a way to post a first question on here. So embarrassing!

Answer (score 2):

Python is case sensitive. `if`, `elif` and `else` should be in lowercase. Additionally, anything you want executed in such a block needs to be indented:

```
def find_weird(n):
    if not n % 2 == 0:
        return "Weird"

    elif n % 2 == 0 and n < 5 and n > 2:
        return "Not Weird"

    elif n % 2 == 0 and n < 20 and n > 6:
        return "Weird"

    elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
        return "Not Weird"
```

Comment: You beat me by 40 seconds :)

Answer (score 0):

`if` and `elif` are not capitalized. Python is case sensitive. Also, you need to indent your code. It should look like this:

```
n = int(input().strip()) 

def find_weird(n):
  if not n % 2 == 0:
    return "Weird"

  elif n % 2 == 0 and n < 5 and n > 2:
    return "Not Weird"

  elif n % 2 == 0 and n < 20 and n> 6:
    return "Weird"

  elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
    return "Not Weird"
```

Answer (score 0):

Three problems I see.

1. If and Elif should not be capitalized.
2. Use `expr1 != expr2` rather than `not expr1 == expr2`
3. Indent your code properly after an if statement.

Try this code instead:

```
n = int(input().strip()) 

def find_weird(n):
    if n % 2 != 0:
        return "Weird"

    elif n % 2 != 0 and n < 5 and n > 2:
        return "Not Weird"

    elif n % 2 == 0 and n < 20 and n > 6:
        return "Weird"

    elif n % 2 == 0 and n > 20:
        return "Not Weird"
```

Comment: Yeah... *he* should fix *his* indentation...

Comment: oops...embarrassing...